# WordPress Issues with Cloud Compute

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm very unfamiliar with Google Cloud Hosting so apologies for my ignorance. I spun up a VM with Wordpress on it and pointed my DNS to the IP. The machine was shut down and when came back up was assigned a new external IP. I am no longer able to access the website even after pointing my DNS to the new IP. Anyone able to point me in the right direction on how I can fix this? I'm guessing starting with grabbing a static IP, but can anyone point me to a guide on how to obtain one and set it up? Lastly, how do I adjust my Wordpress instance to use that IP and point my DNS from an external provider to the VM. I see it's recommended to use a load balancer to increase speed but again, I'm a newbie with all of this and have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to access your WordPress because your original IP was ephemeral and it changed when you stopped the instance and started it again.

To solved this problem you can modifying 2 fields in the DB:

1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the [VM instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.222476955.1653967723.1602508970-638966553.1591892739&_gac=1.148565635.1602166312.EAIaIQobChMI1evg59m36AIVVaqWCh0HFAwSEAAYASAAEgKdEfD_BwE) page to check the new IP for your `WordPress` Instance.
2. Use your new IP to access to your `phpMyAdmin`:

```
https://34.75.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin/
```

If you don't know your credentials to access to phpMyAdmin you can get this information with the following command using ssh:

```
sudo sed -n 1p /home/ubuntu/.db_password
```

3. Once you have access,  go to wordpress -> wp_options
4. Then you edit the option name

- siteurl
- home
  [image]

After this action you should be able to access your site again with the New IP.

#### Reserving a static external IP address

To avoid this issue in the future you could [Reserve your IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign):

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the [VM instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.9507125.1653967723.1602508970-638966553.1591892739&_gac=1.212034080.1602166312.EAIaIQobChMI1evg59m36AIVVaqWCh0HFAwSEAAYASAAEgKdEfD_BwE) page.
2. Click the name of the instance that you want to assign an external IP to. The instance details page displays.
3. From the instance details page, complete the following steps:

a. Click **Edit**.
b. Under **Network interfaces**, click the edit button.

c. Under **External IP**, select **Static external IP** address to assign to the instance.

d. Click Done and Save.

(Note: I'm using a fresh installation of WordPress LiteSpeed)

Comment: What's the point of modifying the site url when the domain hasn't changed?

Comment: The point to modify these fields is to access again to the site. In these fields the IP is stored. I'm pretty sure on this because I have reproduced it in my own project. I have added an screenshot to show you what you will see in those fields. Please don't downvote the answer before test it.  I recommend you to review the following documentation on [When should I vote down?](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

I have HTTP and HTTPS Firewall Allow enabled but I get this error trying to access it (obviously with the full IP in the string).

This site can’t be reached 34.67.xxx.xxx refused to connect. Try:

Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Are you trying to access to https://34.67.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin/ ?  Could you please edit your question to add this information? and if it is possible to a screenshot of the error you are receiving?

Comment: Sorry, yes. https://34.67.214.186/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Please try without the s http://34.67.214.186/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Got in! Thanks. Logged in and the db has been updated but still can't gain access to the site. https://www.dropbox.com/s/he15rbllwjqsvpg/Screen%20Shot%202021-01-06%20at%203.12.25%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: It seems that you have modified something else, due to the last time I access to phpmyadmin I was able to see the logging page without problem, and I was able to ping your IP, but now I can't access to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118136/discussion-between-jose-luis-delgadillo-and-anthony-m).

Comment: Resolved it with your solution. I had to switch to HTTP. Thank you SO much for your help!!

Comment: if you find my answer useful, please consider accepting it, thank you!